# How can I share my iPhone's 3g connection with my Ubuntu 10.10 desktop PC? Currently using MyWi app

Tags: networking, connection, iphone, 3g, tethering

I'm trying to share my iPhone's 3G data connection with my Ubuntu desktop as my broadband router has blown up (a new one is on order...).

I have successfully managed to share my 3G data connection with my Win 7 OS on the same desktop machine, but I'd really like to get it working in Ubuntu, as Win 7 is a real step back for me. On Win 7 I was able to share my mobile data connection by installing the iOS MyWi app on my iPhone and connecting over USB. I tried to share my 3G connection via USB and use the native iOS 'Internet Tethering' feature but Win 7 could not discover the connection.

On Ubuntu I've tried using the MyWi app to share my 3G connection to my Ubuntu desktop via USB but Ubuntu simply cannot 'discover' the network. I also tried to set my iPhone to 'Internet Tethering ON' and manually adding my mobile connection in Ubuntu as a 'Mobile Broadband' and adding the APN for 3UK. I couldn't get Ubuntu to discover the network.

Any ideas please?

My iPhone is 4.01 (jailbroken)
Ubuntu 10.10 (fully up to date so I shouldn't need to install any new iPhone packages, I *thought*)
MyWi app v4.60.14
Data provider is 3 Mobile (UK). I have an unlimited data plan.

Answer (score 1):

I'm now using 11.04 and iPhone 3G's internet connection via bluetooth (works out of the box), but with 10.10 i used an USB cable, and this line in /etc/network/interfaces:

`iface wwan0 inet dhcp`

Then everytime i wanted to get on the net, i would connect the USB cable and run `sudo ifup wwan0` from commandline. This is of course a suboptimal, but it worked for me. I tried some other ways to define the connection, but didn't find a GUI-solution and got used to that method.

Make sure you have `libimobiledevice` -installed. For diagnosing it was useful to keep an eye on system logs, via command `tail -f /var/log/messages` or the Gnome Log File Viewer while connecting the iPhone USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

go to system > preferences > network connections and create a mobile broadband connection.